# Is there an altcoin generator with merged-mining support?

Tags: altcoin, services, altcoin-development

I am wondering - is there a service similar to [CoinCreator](http://coincreator.net/) that allows one to generate altcoins with built-in support for merged mining?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, http://build-a-co.in/ is an alt coin generator that supports merged mining.

In general, I think it has more settings and is easier to correct settings.

Comment: Tech, I don't see any reference of merged mining on that page. It doesn't even seem to let you specify a mining algorithm.